# class incompatiblity when trying to launch jersey inside grizzly?

Tags: java, jersey, grizzly

I'm trying to integrate a hello-world style jersey call into an existing application, using grizzly2.

I've added this dependency to my maven pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

which produces this dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-grizzly2-http:jar:2.22.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http-server:jar:2.3.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http:jar:2.3.23:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-framework:jar:2.3.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.22.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.22.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.22.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.22.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.22.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
```

I'm trying to bring up grizzly as follows:

```
    private static final URI BASE_URI = URI.create("http://localhost:8080/base/");
    public static final String ROOT_PATH = "helloworld";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
            System.out.println("\"Hello World\" Jersey Example App");

            final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(RestTest.class);
            final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, resourceConfig, false);
```

But it results in an error that indicates a mis-matched set of jar files:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.PropertiesHelper.getValue(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/ws/rs/RuntimeType;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature.configure(MoxyJsonFeature.java:60)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:714)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:644)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureMetaProviders(ResourceConfig.java:829)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:453)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.<init>(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:337)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:140)
    at gov.vha.isaac.demo.RestMain.main(RestMain.java:20)
```

I've tried forcing the offending jar (jersey-common) to various different versions, but they all fail in the same way (or worse, if I go back to far)

I've tried different versions of grizzly - but the only version I can get to start - is so old that I now run into issues with an HK2 version mismatch between grizzly and my other code.

How can the grizzly hello world be so difficult to execute?

Or, can someone point me to the silly thing I'm doing wrong?

Comment: One dependency alone will not cause this error. There are other dependencies you are not showing us. In general, keep all your Jersey dependency versions the same. This problem is most likely caused by different Jersey version dependencies.

Comment: If you want to create a project from the Maven archetype, see [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html#new-from-archetype). This will give you a running application for free.

Comment: I'll update further tomorrow, but by knocking out other dependency from my project, I finally got to a point where it would run.  There is some other library I was including, which was somehow - leading to this exception - though I don't yet know how... since I have no other dependencies on the class that had the wrong version.  Going to have to finish going through the dependency tree, and banning things till I figure out which specific library is causing the incompatibility.

Comment: If you post your dependencies, others can help you out ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, this is the dependency chain that was leading to the class-incompatibility:

```
[INFO] |  \- au.csiro:snorocket-core:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |     \- au.csiro:ontology-model:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |           +- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.moxy:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |           |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |           |     \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.asm:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |           \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.antlr:jar:2.5.0:compile
```

Unfortunately, this output from mvn dependency:tree is not correct - as it appears that the maven dependency tree plugin is broken or just has a really silly design.

Because the library org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common is ALSO a dependency later in the project, it didn't print it here.

In reality, org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:jar:2.2 depends on 
org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.2

My grizzly dependency was pulling in org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.22.1

These two versions are incompatible.

Now, if I had been just packaging the project with Maven, it (might) have worked ok - as I think maven is aligning on the 2.22.1 version.  However, I was trying to test in eclipse.  And the m2e plugin for Eclipse does *NOT* appear to properly setup the classpath - rather - it ends up including *BOTH* versions of the jar on the classpath at the same time.

So far, I cannot find anyway to get this to run within eclipse, because m2e insists on including both jars on the classpath - even when I add in an exclusion to try to keep the old version of the jar out.

--edit--

I did finally get it to run by going to the project in eclipse that was depending snorocket-core, and doing an exclusion of jersey-media-moxy, followed by pulling in the newer version of jersey-media-moxy.

This allowed me to finally get m2e to build a proper classpath in eclipse.  It seems that m2e doesn't properly set up the classpath when it includes other local projects on the classpath - it just blindly pulls in all dependencies of a project - without taking into account if that project has a different version of a jar than another project - it doesn't select a single version of a jar to use in the same way that maven does.